# Pose 2 different Objects

Tags: animation

I have a character with a barbell in his hands (http://puu.sh/zlxHk/1c8cd144d7.jpg). Now I want to move the hands and move the barbell with it, how can I do this? Should i extrude a bone from the hand through the barbell (but from which bone would I extrude then?) or how can I solve this?

Thanks!